# I tried to make a QRcode from the user's input file with Python but its not working

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, qr-code

Here is my code:

```python
import qrcode
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root=Tk()

def choosefile():
    global file
    file=filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r',title='Choose a File')

choosefilebutton=Button(root,text='Choose a File',command=choosefile)
choosefilebutton.pack()

def submit():
    qr=qrcode.make(file)
    qr.save('qrcode.png')

choosefilebutton=Button(root,text='Submit',command=submit)
choosefilebutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It makes a QR code but when I scan the QR code the result is:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/charliezhang/Desktop/hello.png' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

I'm new to Python and don't understand everything too well yet
Can someone please help?

Comment: You never actually called `.read()` on the file to get its contents; you made your QR code out of *the file object itself*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get a file path and name data with `askopenfile`.
Should be something like:

```
f = open(file.name)
qr = qrcode.make(f.read())
f.close()
```

Comment: The above is true, but you can more simply call file.read(). Or, with error checking, (file.read() if file else "")

Answer (score 1):

In Py 3.8.10, the following works:

```
def submit():
    if file:
        qr = qrcode.make(file.read())
        qr.save('qrcode.png')
```

Here, `file` returned from `filedialog.askopenfile()` is not a string but a file-like object. So, adding the `.read()` pulls the data from the file. The `filedialog.askopenfilename()` method returns a string which is the name of the file.

I also add a check for file, since if the user hits the Cancel button from the Open File dialog, `file` gets set to None. So doing this check helps prevent another error when the user hits the Submit button afterwards.